# How can i get my program to remove from end of list instead of start in python

Tags: python, stack

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.next = None

class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 0
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def append(self, data):
        node = Node()
        node.data = data
        if not self.head:
            self.head = node
            self.tail = node
            self.size = 1
            return
        self.tail.next = node
        self.tail = node
        self.size += 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Stack(%s)' % str(self)

    def __iter__(self):
        current = self.head
        while current:
            yield current.data
            current = current.next

    def __str__(self):
        return '[%s]' % ', '.join([x for x in self])

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def pop(self):
        data = self.head.data
        self.head = self.head.next
        return data



if __name__ == '__main__':
    list = Stack()

    reply = 0

    while reply!="5":

        print("1. Add to list")
        print("2. Display list")
        print("3. Size of list")
        print("4. Remove from list")
        print("5. Exit")

        reply = int(input("what would you like to do?"))

        if reply == 1:
            data = input("Add an element:")
            list.append(data)
        if reply == 2:
            print(list)
        if reply == 3:
            print(len(list))
        if reply == 4:
            list.pop()

        if reply == 5:
            print("good bye")
```

I'm a fairly new to python , and for a class assignment i have been asked to implement a stack linked list with interface, i understand the basics of a linked list however, when i press 4 it should remove the last element which i have inputted , however it removes the first which is not (stack - last in first out)
Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: In `pop` you are returning the `head ` data, not the `tail`.

Comment: ahh ,what function can i use to remove the last element inserted?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, but i had to make some additional changes to your code

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.next = None

class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 0
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def append(self, data):
        node = Node()
        node.data = data
        if not self.head:
            self.head = node
            self.tail = node
            self.size = 1
            return
        self.tail.next = node
        self.tail = node
        self.size += 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Stack(%s)' % str(self)

    def __iter__(self):
        current = self.head
        while current:
            yield current # change here, return object instead of object data
            current = current.next

    def __str__(self):
        return '[%s]' % ', '.join([str(x.data) for x in self]) # change here

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def pop(self):
        # find last element while keeping track of item next to last
        # set new tail to next to last item and set the next item
        # in the new tail to none

        if self.head == self.tail:
            returnval = self.head
            self.head = None
            self.tail = None
            return returnval
        old_tail_data = self.tail.data
        previous = self.head
        for thing in self:
            if thing != self.tail:
                previous = thing
            if thing == self.tail:
                previous.next = None
                self.tail = previous

        return old_tail_data



if __name__ == '__main__':   
    list = Stack()     
    list.append('ha')
    list.append('ho')
    list.append('go')
    list.pop()
    print(list)
```

Example use

```
list = Stack()     
list.append('ha')
list.append('ho')
list.append('go')
list.pop()
list.pop()
print(list) # should return [ha]
list.append('new1')
list.append('new2')
print(list) # should return [ha,new1,new2]
```

with the Menu

[image: Menu operation]

The menu code

```
list = Stack()

reply = 0

while reply!="5":

    print("1. Add to list")
    print("2. Display list")
    print("3. Size of list")
    print("4. Remove from list")
    print("5. Exit")

    reply = int(input("what would you like to do?"))

    if reply == 1:
        data = input("Add an element:")
        list.append(data)
    if reply == 2:
        print(list)
    if reply == 3:
        print(len(list))
    if reply == 4:
        list.pop()

    if reply == 5:
        print("good bye")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
del l[-1]
```

Instead of pop, because in pop it removes the head data.

Comment: "stack object doesn't  support item deletion"

Comment: @Shivin Agarwal He is trying to create his own linked list object which doesn't have that capability.

Comment: @en_lorithai what do you recommend i do?

Comment: @ralaba You have to change your pop function. It has to change the tail to the second last item in your linked list.

Comment: Ohh sorry, but the answer provided by @en_lorithai, seems working.

Comment: @ShivinAgarwal if the answer worked, mark is as answered :)

Comment: @en_lorithai i have used your pop function , however when i give my own inputs when pressing 'add to list' , and then after i press remove from list it does not remove anything . apologies i;m very inexperienced with this and thank you for your help!

Comment: @ralaba Seems to be working for me. I have added example use in the answer, try it and see if it returns the same for you.

Comment: @en_lorithai  Yes your's seems to be working and gives me a much better understand of how linked list works thank you ! however i'm unsure if i;m being stupid but if you use my menu and press 1 'add to list' 3 times and giving you a list of say [1,2,3] . then you press the remove from list , and finally when you display list it shows nothing being removed and just [1,2,3] still. if you could check my menu and get back to me that would be great.

Comment: reply = 0

    while reply!="5":
        
        print("1. Add to list")
        print("2. Display list")
        print("3. Size of list")
        print("4. Remove from list")
        print("5. Exit")
        
        reply = int(input("what would you like to do?"))

        if reply == 1:
            data = input("Add an element:")
            list.append(data)
        if reply == 2:
            print(list)
        if reply == 3:
            print(len(list))
        if reply == 4:
            list.pop()
     
        if reply == 5:
            print("good bye")

Comment: @ralaba That seems to be working for me to, added image of the use to the answer.

Comment: @en_lorithai would you be able to post your code that you've redone for me with the menu interface code(seems i've muddled mine up) . I OWE YOU A DRINK!

Comment: @ralaba I just used your menu code as is in your question, but i posted a copy of it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pop` method; every [Python list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) defines it:

```
whole = range(5)   # [0,1,2,3]
print whole.pop()  # 4
print whole        # [0, 1, 2, 3]
print whole.pop(0) # 0
print whole        # [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: pop removes the head data , i wish for it to remove from the last.

Comment: Then use `pop()`: @ralaba, see the snippet I posted. `pop(0)` removes the first item.

Comment: @ArielOtilibili He isn't using the built in list object, he is using his own version